# How to Show Pencil Icon when I touch on Html tags like div/canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, model-view-controller, html5-canvas

I have a signature pad using HTML5 Canvas. If user signs inside canvas element I want to show pen/pencil icon as signature progress.

```
                   canvas.onmousemove = canvas.ontouchmove = function (e) {
                    if (x == null || y == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (cdIsmouseIn == true) {
                        hasMoved = true;
                        if (e.changedTouches && e.changedTouches.length > 0) {
                            var first = e.changedTouches[0];
                            x = first.pageX - $(window).scrollLeft();
                            y = first.pageY - $(window).scrollTop();
                        }
                        else {
                            x = e.clientX;
                            y = e.clientY;
                        }
                        x -= $(this).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();
                        y -= $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

                        ctx.lineCap = ctx.lineJoin = "round";

                        ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
                        ctx.shadowColor = "#2d2d2f";// "rgb(0,0,0)";
                        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
                        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
```

Comment: Something like when the touch position changes the pen/pencil icon also moves.[Take real example of writing with pen on a paper]

Comment: Why can't you simply set the icon visibility in the function above?  I don't see how you can write that and then struggle with a simple hide/show.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the mouse pointer to a pencil image when you mouse over the canvas. Something like this:

```
$("#canvasID").mouseover(function()
{
    $(this).css( 'cursor', 'url(/Images/pencilIcon.png), auto' );
});
```

I haven't tried but this should work.